# Block an adresse IP on firewall after detectinf port scan in ELK SIEM

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am using elastic stack SIEM and I wanna know if there is a solution to interact with my firewall.
SO after that the SIEM detect a port scanner I wanna that it adds a rule automatically in my firewall and block that IP addresse.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have licences, you can use alerts for this.
Alerts allow to call a web-service on detection.

You can then call your firewall, or call a micro service to call your firewall or update your blacklist.

You can see the reference here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/actions-webhook.html